# Delete Sharedpreferences on button click

Tags: android

I'm a beginner to android. I have passed a sharedpreferences  to intent activity. I want to remove it on button click by user. How can I execute that in code? I tried different ways but did not succeed.
Thank you.

Code below

```
            String computer_name = ComputerName.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences computerNamePrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor computerNameeditor = computerNamePrefs.edit();
            computerNameeditor.putString("COMPUTERNAME",computer_name);
            computerNameeditor.commit();

            Intent computerIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SelectedService.class);
            startActivity(computerIntent);

            // SelectedService Activity below

            computer_brandname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.COMPUTER_BRAND);
            final SharedPreferences computerPreference = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE,0);
            String computerName = computerPreference.getString("COMPUTERNAME","");
            computer_brandname.setText(computerName);

           removeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.remove);
    removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          // i am unable to figure out this code

        }

    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Can you include one or two snippets of attempted code in the question. It could be a very simple problem.

Answer (score 3):

Retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are private to this activity.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("YOUR PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.clear().apply(); //remove all

//OR

editor.remove("KEY").apply(); //remove by key
```

use with click

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         editor.remove("KEY").apply(); //remove by key
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SharedPreference.Editor pref = context.getSharedPreferences("A_PREFS_FILE", 0).edit();
pref.clear();
pref.commit();
```