# clearing shared preferences when button clicked

Tags: java, android

So I have had a look at [Delete Sharedpreferences on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46547187/delete-sharedpreferences-on-button-click) this post, and tried the code, but when I ran it on my app, only my textviews disappeared and everything else stayed?

This is the snippet of code: (it's a button on an overflow menu)

```
else if (id == R.id.action_delete) {
            //code to delete list here.

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

            editor.clear().apply();


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "List removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
```

My full code

```
public class create extends AppCompatActivity {


    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    private ArrayList<SearchableSpinner> mSpinners;
    private List<AppCompatButton> mButtons = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<CheckBox> mCheckboxes = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<TextView> mTextviews = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<EditText> mEdittexts = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<View> mViews = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<String, String> numberItemValues = new HashMap<>();
    private Spinner spinner;
    private TextView textview;
    private CheckBox checkbox;
    List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    LinearLayout verticallayout,horizontalLayout;
    public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";







    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        findViewById(R.id.my_linearLayout).requestFocus();

        verticallayout = findViewById(R.id.verticalLayout); //got






        //Arrays
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(String.valueOf(mSpinners)); // add you selected item
        mSpinners = new ArrayList<>();




        //Initializing Variables Here
        mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_linearLayout);
        //verticallayout = findViewById(R.id.verticalLayout);
        textview = findViewById(R.id.textview);
        checkbox = findViewById(R.id.checkbox);





        //TODO getting shared prefs on create
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray2 = new JSONArray(prefs.getString("key", null));
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray2.length(); i++) {



                final Spinner spinner = makeSpinner();
                mLinearLayout.addView(spinner);

                final View newView = makeView();
                //Add a new view
                mLinearLayout.addView(newView);
                mViews.add(newView);


              /* final EditText newEdittext = makeEdittext();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newEdittext);
                mEdittexts.add(newEdittext);



                final CheckBox newCheckbox = makeCheckbox();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newCheckbox);

                //TODO add checkbox to your list
                mCheckboxes.add(newCheckbox);*/

                createRow();


                final TextView newTextview = makeTextview();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newTextview);
                mTextviews.add(newTextview);








                final int listSize = mViews.size();

                //TODO deleting item
                horizontalLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    //start
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        //when the 'new button' is pressed, alert shows if you are sure you want to delete the item or not.

                        final View.OnClickListener context = this;


                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(create.this);


                        // set title
                        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete Item");

                        // set dialog message
                        alertDialogBuilder
                                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, close
                                        // current activity


                                        if (listSize > 0) {

                                            //mCheckboxes.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mSpinners.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            // mSpinners.remove(listSize - 1);

                                            mViews.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mTextviews.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            // mEdittexts.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }


                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        // show it
                        alertDialog.show();


                    }
                });





                int positionOfSpinner = (int) jsonArray2.get(i);
                spinner.setSelection(positionOfSpinner);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //end of shared pref  code








        //TODO FAB BUTTON
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =
                (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);


        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);



                // Handle ze click.
                final Spinner spinner = makeSpinner();
                mLinearLayout.addView(spinner);


                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) spinner.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.setMargins(5, 100, 10, 0); //top 70

                Resources resources = getResources();
                DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();

                layoutParams.height = (int) (70 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)); //80
                layoutParams.width = (int) (240 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)); //240
                spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                final View newView = makeView();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newView);
                mViews.add(newView);


               /* final EditText newEdittext = makeEdittext();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newEdittext);
                mEdittexts.add(newEdittext);*/

                createRow();

                final int listSize = mViews.size();

                //code for deleting the said item.



                horizontalLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    //start
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        //when the 'new button' is pressed, alert shows if you are sure you want to delete the item or not.

                        final View.OnClickListener context = this;


                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(create.this);



                        // set title
                        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete Item");

                        // set dialog message
                        alertDialogBuilder
                                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, close
                                        // current activity


                                        if (listSize > 0) {

                                            //mCheckboxes.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mSpinners.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mSpinners.remove(listSize - 1);
                                            mViews.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            mTextviews.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            //mEdittexts.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        // show it
                        alertDialog.show();


                    }
                });

                //Add a new checkbox
               /* final CheckBox newCheckbox = makeCheckbox();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newCheckbox);

                //TODO add checkbox to your list
                mCheckboxes.add(newCheckbox);*/




                final TextView newTextview = makeTextview();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newTextview);
                mTextviews.add(newTextview);

                //TODO Add the spinner on item selected listener to get selected items
                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                        String currentItem = itemList.get(position);
                        String aisleNumber = numberItemValues.get(currentItem);
                        //TODO you can use the above aisle number to add to your text view
                        //mTextviews.get(mTextviews.size() -1).setText(aisleNumber);
                        newTextview.setText(aisleNumber);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                        //  code here, do nothing
                    }

                });


            }
        });

    }



















    //TODO OVERFLOW MENU
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.create_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            /*Intent startSettingsActivity = new Intent(this, AppCompatPreferenceActivity.class);
            startActivity(startSettingsActivity);
            //start the settings activity here.*/

            startActivity(new Intent(create.this, settings.class));





            return true;
        }


        else if (id == R.id.action_delete) {
            //code to delete list here.

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

            editor.clear().apply();


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "List removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }


        else if (id ==R.id.action_help)  {


            // setup the alert builder
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Help");
            builder.setMessage("To use this app, first go to Create your Shopping List.\n" +
                    "Here, you can add items to your list. Once you have added all items, you can click the menu at the top right corner (or if it doesnt appear press your menu button beside your home button on your device, then click View your List.\n" +
                    "This will take you to the screen where you can view you shopping list with the items in aisle order to make your shop much easier.\n" +
                    "You can still add items at this point. Press the white background of each item to delete the item if you wish.");

            // add a button
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);

            // create and show the alert dialog
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();


            return true;

        }




        else if (id == R.id.action_gotoview) {


            //takes the size of the list of spinners, for reference
            ArrayList<Integer> spinnerList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < mSpinners.size(); i++) {
                spinnerList.add(mSpinners.get(i).getSelectedItemPosition());

            }
            Bundle newBundle = new Bundle();
            newBundle.putIntegerArrayList("arraylist", spinnerList);
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(create.this, viewscreen.class);
            newIntent.putExtra("extraBundle", newBundle);

            startActivity(newIntent);



            //code to go to view screen, aka intent
            return true;
        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }






    public void createRow(View view){

        createRow(); //got

    }


    private void createRow() { //got

        horizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams horizontalParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        horizontalParams.height = 80;
        horizontalParams.setMargins(0, 15, 0, 15); // LEFT, TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM
        horizontalLayout.setLayoutParams(horizontalParams);
        horizontalLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.addButtons));


        makeEdittext();
        makeCheckbox();



        verticallayout.addView(horizontalLayout, horizontalParams);
    }







    //DUPLICATING ITEMS WHEN FAB IS PRESSED//
    private CheckBox makeCheckbox() {
        //Create new Checkbox
        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);

        // Setup layout
  /*      LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        //setup relative layout for the positioning of the objects
        Resources resources = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (70 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)), (int) (240 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)));
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.textview);

        checkbox.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
        checkbox.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);*/



        LinearLayout.LayoutParams checkParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        checkParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        checkParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

        checkbox.setLayoutParams(checkParams);
        horizontalLayout.addView(checkbox);


        return checkbox;
    }



    private TextView makeTextview() {
        //create new textview
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);

        //setup layout

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        /*LinearLayout.LayoutParams editParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        editParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        editParams.width = 70;
        editParams.height = 50;

        textview.setLayoutParams(editParams);
        horizontalLayout.addView(textview);*/
        textview.setTextSize(30);

        return textview;
    }



    private EditText makeEdittext() {
        //create new edittext
        EditText edittext = new EditText(this);

        //setup layout
       /* final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70, 50); // Width , height
        edittext.setLayoutParams(lparams);*/



        LinearLayout.LayoutParams editParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        editParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        editParams.width = 70;
        editParams.height = 50;

        edittext.setLayoutParams(editParams);
        horizontalLayout.addView(edittext);


        edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
        edittext.setHint("qty");

        return edittext;

    }

//set the  3d effect to view

    private View makeView() {
        //create new View

        View view = new View(this);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100);
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50);


        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


        view.setClickable(true);

        //view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


        //setup layout

        return view;


    }














    private Spinner makeSpinner() {
        //opens csv
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
        CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
        //TODO I made this variable global, declared it at the very top of this file
        itemList = csvFile.read();

        //Create new spinner
        // SearchableSpinner spinner = (SearchableSpinner) new Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN);
        SearchableSpinner spinner = new SearchableSpinner(this);


        // Setup layout

     /*   LinearLayout.LayoutParams spinnerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        spinnerParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        spinnerParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

        Resources resources = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();

        spinnerParams.height = (int) (70 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)); //80
        spinnerParams.width = (int) (240 * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)); //240

        spinner.setLayoutParams(spinnerParams);
        horizontalLayout.addView(spinner);*/

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);



        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, R.id.txtid, itemList);


        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);





        //Add it to your list of spinners so you can retrieve their data when you click the getSpinner button
        mSpinners.add(spinner);








        return spinner;
    }



    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read() {

            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    //TODO I edited this part so that you'd add the values in our new hash map variable
                    numberItemValues.put(row[1], row[0]);
                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }


    //on stop, the things are saved into shared prefs
    @Override
    protected void onStop () {

        //public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < mSpinners.size(); i++) {
            jsonArray.put(mSpinners.get(i).getSelectedItemPosition());

        }

        editor.putString("key", jsonArray.toString());
        editor.apply();


        super.onStop();
    }

}
```

Comment: basically your shared preferences are not deleted right?

Comment: yeah...well when I reinstalled the app and added new  elemnts to my app by pressing the FAB, only the  textviews disappear when I press the delete button

Answer (score 0):

Try this to clear shared preferences:

```
else if (id == R.id.action_delete) {
    //code to delete list here.
    getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().commit();

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "List removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: all the stuff on the screen still stayed there.

Comment: ok, you should update views after that. Clearing the preferences is not enough.

Comment: Your approach to create UI is not recommended. You should use RecyclerView, ListView, ... instead. However, you can put the codes that create views corresponding to preference values in a method named initViews, then call it in onCreate. Also, after clearing the preferences, try to call removeAllViews() from LinearLayouts, then call initViews.

Comment: what do you mean by corresponding to preference values?

Comment: I just put ```mLinearLayout.removeAllViews();```  in the else if statement. is that wrong? it removes all the views and the screen is blaank which is good, but then when i get out of the activity and go back, those views come back